# search and replace text in all php-files in a directory and it's subdirectories

Tags: bash, shell

I am trying to replace a string in all PHP files within a directory and it's subdirectory!

So in order to do that I created 2 text files, namely "pattern.txt"(Contains string to be replaced) and "replacement.txt" (Contains the replacement string)

I fired up my gitBash Shell on Windows 10 and typed in the following command

```
pattern=`cat /path/to/pattern`; replacement=`cat /path/to/replacement`
find . -name "*.php" | xargs -n 1 sed -i -e 's|$pattern|$replacement|g'
```

But an error arises after executing the second command, which is

sed: can't read ./admin: No such file or directory

Please help!

Answer (score 0):

You could avoid using `xargs` and do everything within `find` for example:

```
find . -name "*.php" -exec sed -i '' 's/pattern/replacement/g' {} +
```

On BSD, MAC by passing an empty string to sed’s -i args will create no backup `sed -i ''`